# Redis fails to create a database snapshot larger than 5120000 bytes

Tags: ubuntu, redis, phpredis

When database is larger than `5120000` bytes Redis fails it to save and crushes.

I run it on `Ubuntu Server 14.04`, `Redis v.3.0.1`.

I updated `/etc/sysctl.conf`

`vm.overcommit_memory = 1`

`net.core.somaxconn=1024`

and
`/etc/rc.local`

`echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`

as it was recommended in redis log.

I insert test data total of around 200MB with 80000 keys

then from command-line I execute `BGSAVE`.

A message `Background saving started` is returned and

`* Background saving started by pid 6535`

`# Background saving terminated by signal 25`

is logged

then I execute `SAVE` from command-line
it creates

`5120000 Dec 22 17:24 temp-4975.rdb` file and crashes:

`Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`

When dumping smaller amount of data everything goes well.

Is there a limit of 5120000 bytes per file?
What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: See last response on this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/bNZNp8xiR8A It says you should increase your `maxmemory` settings.

Comment: ```maxmemory``` is set to ```1536mb```

Comment: Did you reboot your server after changing the configuration? You have only described changes in config files, or files used at start time.

Comment: @Didier Spezia all changes applied, on server's boot I got
```cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled```
```always madvise [never]```

```cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory```
```1```

```/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn```
```1024```